# How to set the flexbox width only to the content within

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I set the width of the flexbox container to the width of the content within? Can it behave like `display:inline-block`, without specifying a fixed width

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5m27oxtp/1/)

Comment: Try `inline-flex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.parent {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}

.flex {
   display: inline-flex;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    background: blue;
}
```